# Execute Apple Shortcut in Background

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, guided-access, ipados

With URL schemes you can launch a shortcut (shortcuts app) from your app via a URL scheme. You can even add a callback to the URL so that the app gets opened again after the shortcut is executed (See https://support.apple.com/en-nz/guide/shortcuts/apdcd7f20a6f/ios)

I'm currently writing an app for people with disabilities, which runs in guided access mode. I want to execute a shortcut with a button tap in the app. The app shouldn't leave guided access mode and also, the shortcuts UI might be distracting for the user.

Is there a way to execute a shortcut in the background?

Comment: you can try this : https://www.idownloadblog.com/2019/05/27/how-to-schedule-shortcuts/